# Disable function in NodeJS for a while

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any option to disable function call for a while? for example you can call this function only once per 5 seconds.

Here is my code I would like call max once per 5 seconds:

```
var rest =  require.main.require('./src/Core/WebService/RESTful');

module.exports = {

  updateTimetableData: function(config) {
    var url = 'http://' + config.pttIpAddress + ':' + config.pttServerPort + '/api/';
    var requestUrl = url + 'updatetimetabledata?ipAddress=' + config.pttIpAddress + '&macAddress=' + config.pttMacAddress + '&appVersion=' + config.appVersion;
    rest.getDataFromRESTWebService(requestUrl);
  }

}
```

This method can be called by client rest service and from server code also.

Comment: You can use a flag that will prevent any processing and set this flag to false after 5 secs

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable (outside the function).
2. When the function is called, compare the time stored in the variable with the current time. If the difference is less than 5 seconds: immediately return.
3. Store the current time in the variable

Comment: Ok, but in nodejs every method call is a new process, maybe I dont know about something but in your example I need more a singleton than variable. I wrote new code with your suggestions, but it doesn't work.